# Test in K6 use async how wrote code waiting for a response before executing another request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, async-await, k6

I'm looking for a solution but I've gone through various configurations but haven't been able to get a satisfactory result.

What do I need to do? The queue takes 4 IDs and passes them on for execution one by one, wait until the task on the queue ends or the time for executing the task exceeds, then it takes the next one.

So, I need to take a list of 4 ids, which are executed in the queue. First, one ID adds the request url and needs to wait until the execution finishes and returns a response. If the execution time exceeds 7 min. this should return me http code 400.
Initially, I would like the entire test to last a maximum of 30 minutes.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { expect } from 'https://jslib.k6.io/k6chaijs/4.3.4.3/index.js';
import { check, sleep } from 'k6';


let idsParam = `
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
`;

let params = {
  timeout: '780s',

};


export const optons = {
  vus: 1,
  timeout: '480s',
  duration: '10m',
};

let data = idsParam.trim().split('\n').slice(1).map(row => row.trim());

export default async function () {

    for (let id of data) {
        let url = `https://pagequeue.com/task/{id}`;

        console.info(`Request for ID ${id} `);
        let res = await http.asyncRequest('GET', url, null, params);
        
            // Wait until the request is processed
        if (res.status != 200) {
          console.warn(`Request for ID ${id} is still processing with status ${res.status}...`);
          console.warn(res);
          sleep(60);
        } 


        // Check if the response status is 200 or 400, mark as failure otherwise
        check(res, {
        'Status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200,
        });

        // Check if the response status is 200 or 400, mark as failure otherwise
        check(res, {
        'Status is 400': (r) => r.status === 400,
        });
        
        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    }
    
}
```

For tasks that are on the queue up to 1 min. it works great, but for requests that take longer 3 minutes, not wait but take another request with id. Despite increasing the timeout waiting for asynchronous responses from the http request, it doesn't work for me, only the test ends, also despite setting the time to 20 minutes. it ends after 10m 30sec. On the queue side, the service is prepared to return http code responses.
I checked this on jmeter and it works beautifully there. Currently I need to use my k6 to write a test. Can anyone suggest what it should look like?

Comment: Why do you output that the request is still processing when you get 400? What do you intend to achieve with the sleep of 60? It seems useless. Why do you have `to.equal(200)` when clearly your code expects 400 to be returned as well...

Comment: Thank You for Your question. I wrote code what i need bottom.

Comment: Answering your question is fine, but the question has not been clarified, which should happen in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my case. Maybe it will be useful to someone. What i wrote:

```js
import http from 'k6/http';
import { check, sleep } from 'k6';
import { describe } from 'https://jslib.k6.io/k6chaijs/4.3.4.3/index.js';

let params = {
    timeout: '420s'
};

let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

export let options = {
    vus: 1, 
};


function sendRequest(id) {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let url = `https://pagequeue.com/task/${id}`;
        let res = http.get(url, params);

        let checkRes = check(res, {
            'Status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200,
        });

        if (!checkRes) {
            reject(`Request for ID ${id} failed with status ${res.status}`);
            console.log('Response time was ' + String(res.timings.duration) + ' ms');
        } else {
            console.log(`Request for ID ${id} completed with status ${res.status}`);
            console.log('Response time was ' + String(res.timings.duration) + ' ms');

            resolve();
        }
    });
}

async function runQueue() {

    for (const [index, id] of data.entries()) {
        
        try {
            await sendRequest(id);
            continue;
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        }
    }
}

export default function() {

    describe('[Queue service] Run task from list by id', () => {
        runQueue();
    });
}
```

On the top i added `params` where put timeout, how long we wait for finish request. Default value for timeout is 60 seconds.